# Copying elemets from another list (saved in companion object) and modfying them also reflecting modifications to the original companion object

Tags: android, list, kotlin, companion-object

I have an `Activity A` which has:

```
class ActivityA {
   companion object {
        var list: MutableList<Person> = //objects are acquired here. 
   }
}
```

In `ActivityB`, I copy this list to a variable.

```
class ActivityB {

    var copyList: MutableList<Person> = ActivityA.list.toMutableList() 
}
```

After that I am changing some data of the `copyList`. For example, let's change name of any element. Let's say original `list` has `list.get(0).name = "Bruno"`. Now, change to something else.

```
 copyList.get(0).name = "Alex"
```

Problem is this is also causing the element at index 0 to be also changed in `list`. Which means `list.get(0).name` and `copyList.get(0).name` has the same names "Alex" now.

How can I make sure that original `list` elements are not changed even though `copyList` elements are changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define a method which makes a copy of `Person` (and probably of any of its fields recursively or you'll run into a similar problem). If it's a `data class`, there is already a `copy()` method, but note it won't copy the fields. And on JVM you can use `Cloneable` to get a default implementation for non-data classes as described in https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-use-cloneable/2364, but it's generally not recommended.

Anyway, after you have it,

```
var copyList: MutableList<Person> = ActivityA.list.mapTo(mutableListOf<Person>()) { it.copy() }
```

But this is part of why you should prefer immutability in the first place.